# how to upload folders and files to google storage bucket?

Tags: plugins

There are lots of plugins to transfer contents to google storage bucket, but that all works only when uploaded to media library,
I have lots of audio files in my shared hosting WordPress site, I like to transfer all those audio files folder-wise to the google cloud storage.
I can even handle the playing part(playing files from the cloud).

Comment: Just copy the files over and set up a redirect on your site? I don't see what the problem is. Please explain what you have tried and what didn't work.

Comment: hi, thanks, i am using a media website , so i upload lot of media files thru ftp. I like to copy the files from my hosting to the google cloud storage. are there any plugins to do that work?. I have already tried wp-stateless plugin, but that copies files only from media library.

Comment: I have SSH console access on my hosting plan, is it possible to use command line to copy files from my hosting to the google cloud storage bucket?